# how to display multiple buttons in the right side?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know why my code isn't displaying multiple button in the right side.

Here it is

```css
.btn1 {
  background-color: #yellow;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 1px;
  float: right;
  border: none;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="test">
    <button class="btn1">Info</button>

    <div> write something here </div>

    <button class="btn1">Info 2</button>
    <div> write something here </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Expected Result. Suppose below is the screen

-----------------------------------|

```
        |Info| |Info 2|
```

-----------------------------------|

Comment: you have a conflict with btn css float combined with div.test css as flex

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Where to want the text within the divs to show?

Comment: Perhaps post a picture of what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn1 {
  background-color: #yellow;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 1px;
  float: right;
  border: none;
  order:1;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? It's not very clear where you want the `write something here` text to be. But this takes the 2 buttons and aligns them to the right of the bar.

```css
.btn1 {
  background-color: #yellow;
  color: white;
  margin-right:1px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
}
.test {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color:blue;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
     <button class="btn1">Info</button>

     <button class="btn1">Info 2</button>
  </div>
<div> write something here </div>
     <div> write something here </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test {
  display:flex;
  background:gray;
  align-items:center;
}

.child1 {
  flex-grow:1;
}
.child {
  padding-right:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

    <div class="child1">
    
          <div> write something here </div>
          <div> write something here </div>
          
    </div>
    
    <div class="child2">
    
          <button class="btn1">Info</button>
          <button class="btn1">Info 2</button>
          
    </div>

     
     
  </div>
```